# Optimize Swift Game Textures and Animations

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sprite-kit, textures

At first my Swift 3.0 IOS game ran at about 55-60 FPS which seemed to be alright, but as the game has increased in size over time the FPS have began to drop.  Currently I am seeing the game drop to about 30.0 FPS quickly after beginning.  Currently all of my textures sit in a Assets.xcassets folder not in any particular groups just one after the other and I call them as I need them for animations, SKNodes, etc.  Could this be the reason that my FPS has dropped so much?  I have done research into using a Texture atlas, but is there a way to preload all of these textures using a loading screen, and would that speed up my game?

The game tops out at about 110 nodes at any given time I'm not sure if this is considered a lot of nodes for the phone to handle?

Typically this is how I load my textures for animations:

```
    ///WALK TEXTURES APPENDED TO TEXTURE ARRAYS///
    for i in 1...12{
        //Name of image to append to SKTexture
        let name = "enemy\(i)";
        let redname = "redenemyrun\(i)";
        let blackname = "blackenemy\(i)";

        if i <= 6 {
            enemyRightTextures.append(SKTexture(imageNamed: name));
            redEnemyRightTextures.append(SKTexture(imageNamed: redname));
            blackEnemyRightTextures.append(SKTexture(imageNamed: blackname));
        }
        if i > 6{
            enemyLeftTextures.append(SKTexture(imageNamed: name));
            redEnemyLeftTextures.append(SKTexture(imageNamed: redname));
            blackEnemyLeftTextures.append(SKTexture(imageNamed: blackname));
        }

    }

    ///WALKING ANIMATIONS///
    animateEnemyWalkRight = SKAction.animate(with: enemyRightTextures, timePerFrame: 0.08, resize: true, restore: false);
    animateEnemyWalkLeft = SKAction.animate(with: enemyLeftTextures, timePerFrame: 0.08, resize: true, restore: false);
```

Also does Xcode provide a useful tool for debugging the cause of this issue.

If someone could maybe provide an example of preloading in a didMoveTo() function, I think that would make this thread helpful to all.
Thanks.

Comment: Your first step should be to use the Time Profiler instrument to understand which portions of your code take the longest to execute.

Comment: Modern hardware can handle thousands of nodes no problem. 1. Which device are you using? 2. Are these textures preloaded in `didMoveTo`, or are they loaded in something like `update` or a touch function?

Comment: On iPhone the maximum fps is 60. You can't get 65...

Comment: Thanks for the advice from all. @Fluidity I am using a 6s plus, the textures are not preloaded in didMoveTo they are just created as the SKSpriteNodes are created, which is generally when different timers trigger.

Comment: @Whirlwind It was suppose to be 55-60 I have edited the question, thanks.

Comment: Check your draws count (view.showsDrawsCount = true) and tell us what it says... Of course you should use atlases and preloading if needed. Also there is a pooling... You dont want to create a sprite when needed most of the time. You want to pre-create it and re-use it.

Comment: Ok I will update this with the draws count once I am able to get it.

Comment: SKTexture init is very expensive, if you call on every render, maybe can have fps drops, on this case recommend use a singleton pattern :)